# Could not find any CSX files on Visual Studio Code for Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Every time now when I open VSC I get the message "Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details."

In the output I get this message:

```
"[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files"
```

I have tried to delete and install it again but with no change. Can anyone tell me what is going on and a fix? I have searched around and am not having luck myself.

Comment: I have been facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: this is not a bug. This is just an informative message in the OmniSharp Log that it didn't find CSX files. Since you aren't using CSX, that's 100% expected.

This post above is from https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1579. It seems like a bug to me since it is annoying...

Answer (score -1):

I ran into same issue.  Found out it was the package reference, below, in my .csproj file.  More than likely a recent package reference you added.

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" Version="1.1.2">

I did not have the proper closing forward slash as shown below...

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" Version="1.1.2" />